# Failed to load module script (milkdown)

Tags: html, typescript, pnpm

After downloading repo *https://stackblitz.com/github/Milkdown/examples/tree/main/vanilla-commonmark?file=index.html*
and installing pnpm when i start server i get error in console

**"Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "video/mp2t". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec."**

Somebody know how to fix it?